# prove $p|\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)^p-2^{p+1}$

Tags: prime-numbers

Can anyone help me?  I know that first part is never an integer and second is, so how is possible that the number which is not an integer is divisible by an integer?
p is prime number and p>2

Comment: Have you tried looking at the binomial expansion so see if you can cancel anything?

Comment: $(2+\sqrt{5})^p = a+b\sqrt{5}$, for $a,b$ integers. There's no way to cancel with $2^{p+1}$ to get an integer. Probably this is a mistake or is a division in another sense as commented by Peter.

Comment: What ring are we working in? Should $\sqrt 5$ perhaps be understood as the square root mod $p$?

Comment: Since diff_math's idea (and mine) does not seem to work, SBareS' idea might be what is meant. But what, if the prime is, lets say $17$ ? Then, $5$ is no quadratic residue, so has no "square-root"

Comment: In what context did you find this problem?

Comment: If $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5,$ then $5$ is a quadratic residue, there is some number $s$ with $s^2 \equiv 5 \pmod p.$

Comment: @Will But $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ 0 \equiv (\color{}{2\!+\!s})^{\large p}\! - 2(2^{\large p}) \equiv 2+s-4\,\Rightarrow\, s\equiv 2\,\Rightarrow\, 4\equiv s^2\equiv 5\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid 1\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$ $\qquad\quad $

Comment: @BillDubuque sure. I did not go into the problem itself, i was just suggesting a possible way to interpret $\sqrt 5;$ as you say, that does not work either. Given the lack of response from the OP, this is just another problem that was incorrectly paraphrased for this site.